# Factorization of $x^7 - 1$ into irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb{F_2}[x]$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Can anybody explain to me how to find such a factorization? I have yet to find some kind of "algorithm" to do it properly. I know that

$$x^7 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$$

with $(x-1)$ being irreducible. But how to I factorize the second polynomial further? Plus, are those factorizations always unique or are there several factorizations for the same polynomial?

Comment: I'm so sorry for a wrong hint.

Comment: @Fakemistake Your username . . . implies that it might have been . . . intentional. . . . ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Berlekamp Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) we obtain
$$
x^7-1=(x^3 + x^2 + 1)(x^3 + x + 1)(x + 1).
$$
The factorization is unique, up to permutations and units, because the polynomial ring $\Bbb{F_2}[x]$ is a UFD.

Comment: @nevergraduating Ah, the eternal question: an before a word that begins with a vowel...or whenever the next words *sounds* like beginning with a vowel? Nobody seems to know **for sure** ...

Comment: @nevergraduating Ah, yes. I appreciate your help; English is still difficult for me:)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that such a thing exist! Could you go a little bit more into detail on how exactly you use the algorithm here?

Comment: No problem. It's a bit rude to point it out but I can't help it sometimes.

Comment: Julian, in practice I would use the algorithm only for more difficult cases, and then with a computer. Here you can just do it by hand without any algorithm (but you have asked for it). It is easy to produce a list of irreducible monic polynomials of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Then we see that our poylnomial is not divisible by them. So we need to use degree $3$.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on that, please? I just don't see how to do it from the beginning to the end. "So we need to use degree 3" - what does that mean?

Comment: We need to decompose $x^6+\cdots =(x^3+\cdots)(x^3+\cdots)$. Now just compare coefficients, and you are done. The only possibility is the product of $x^3+x^2+1$ and $x^3+x+1$.

Comment: But how do I compare them?

Comment: Compare them by multiplying out: $(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(x^3+a'x^2+b'x+c')$. Then compare each coefficient with $x^6+\cdots +1$. It follows that $c=c'=1$, and so on. You can make it shorter by realizing that we can only use two cubic polynomials, namely the monic irreducible ones. Then you see that $(x^3+x+1)^2$ and $(x^3+x^2+1)^2$ give the wrong result, but $(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1)$ gives the right one.

Comment: But doesn't multiplying them out does take like forever?

Comment: It takes me three seconds to compute $(x^3+x+1)^2$ modulo $2$.

Comment: And why did you calculate that´?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have lots of ways of doing it, right? Your polynomial is a $6$<sup>th</sup> degree polynomial without roots in $\mathbb{F}_2$. Therefore, if it is reducible, it will have irreducible factors of degree $2$ or $3$. There is only one quadratic irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, which is $x^2+x+1$. And there are only two cubic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, which are $x^3+x+1$ and $x^3+x^2+1$.

Comment: Well, but what would be the approach if I didn't know how many quadratic irreducible polyomials there are? How do I calculate this "from the scratch"?

Comment: @Julian I' confused by your question. What did I do which was *not* “from the scratch”? A polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ with degree $2$ or $3$ is irreducible if and only if it has no roots (this holds for any field). There are only $3$ such polynomials: $q(x)=x^2+x+1$, $c_1(x)=x^3+x+1$, and $c_2(x)=x^3+x^2+1$. Then I divided your polynomial by $q(x)$, but it turned out the the remainder was not $0$. But when I divided it by $c_1(x)$, what I got was $c_2(x)$.